# Jira DVCS Connector does not link commit to issues

Tags: dvcs, jira, ondemand

Im trying to figure out how DVCS Connector plugin works. Im trying to link my commits to Jira issues.

As far as I can tell it seems like my setup is correct. At least it doesnt complain about anything.

I add my issue to the comment like "MBL-10 Fixed some minor issues with.." but they are not linked with the issue.

When I try to push the "Force Sync" button it say "Last commit 7 hours ago" and it's beein saying that the entire day.

Anyone bumped into similar problems before?

Btw, Im using Jira OnDemand.

Comment: I now saw "1 issues found" when performing "Force Sync", but it still say "7 hours ago" - and the issue does not contain any commits.

Comment: I posted a ticket to the support team at Atlassian and they are working on this issue now. I will update the post if they figure out something that can help others with similar problems. This does however look like a bug on their side.

Comment: Remove all DVCS account and reconnect all